# How to configure Openshift to not use cache when pulling image from external Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, openshift

I created a docker image and uploaded it to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/barak1412/docker_test/general).

My goal is that every time a pod is created, Openshift will pull the image from Docker Hub, while ignoring any cache it has.

I created a new app using the following command:

```
oc new-app --docker-image=docker.io/barak1412/docker_test:v1 --name=docker-test-app
```

And also changed the image pulling policy in the development YAML:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

But still, Openshift keeps loading the image from somewhere in its internal cache, and as a result, the application is not updating.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this property `imagePullPolicy: Always` is the correct way. However, note that there is no way no you can disable the ImageStreams (internal cache) on OpenShift by default. The first time kubernetes pulled the image from the DockerHub, this image with the exact digest is cached. So the next time you try to pull, kubelet queries for the exact digest locally and pulls with the resolved digest.

Always

> *every time the kubelet launches a container, the kubelet queries the container image registry to resolve the name to an image digest. If the kubelet has a container image with that exact digest cached locally, the kubelet uses its cached image; otherwise, the kubelet pulls the image with the resolved digest, and uses that image to launch the container.*

If you want OpenShift to pull a new image from DockerHub:

1. Push a new image to DockerHub with the same tag `v1`. This new image will have a new digest created by DockerHub itself.
2. Now, delete the pod on your cluster.
3. Since you've the `ImagePullPolicy` set to `always`, kubelet will first check local cache's image (ImageStreams) and try to match with the new image and it's digest value.
4. Since the new image you pushed in step 1 has a different digest, kubelet will pull the new image from DockerHub, instead of pulling from the local cache

Reference:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy

Answer (score 1):

When you create an application using `oc new-app`, not only do you create a `Deployment` but in the background an `ImageStream` is configured as well. The application in the Deployment then references this [ImageStream](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html#images-imagestream-use_image-streams-managing).

So to update your `Deployment` do one of the following:

- Edit your `Deployment` using `oc edit deployment <name>` and set the Docker Hub container image as the `image`.
- Use `oc get is` to find the name of your ImageStream and then use `oc import-image <name>` to update it to the latest version. You can enable automatic updates by using `--scheduled`: [Configuring periodic importing of image stream tags](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html#images-imagestream-import_image-streams-managing)

Comment: Regarding the first solution: I already tried that, but it is still loaded from some cache. For the second one, I want the same image with the same tag, what do you mean by latest version? Thanks.

Comment: If you specify „ImagePullPolicy: Always“ there should not be any caching involved. For the second option, you can just specify the same image with the same tag again, then that one will be updated.